# Been trying to prove that $n! = \Omega(n^{100})$. I was approaching it with the solution below. I am not really sure my assumptions

Tags: asymptotics, sorting

We know that:
$$f(n) = n! = \Omega (g(n)$$
if
$$g(n) = O(f(n))$$
then,
$$f(n) \in O(g(n))$$
If
$$ f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n) \quad \textbf{for all $n\geq 1$}$$
then, assuming $n=1$ and $c=100^{100}$:
$$n^{100} \leq 100^{100}\cdot n! \quad \textbf{for all $n\geq 1$}$$
\textbf{Base Case}: $n=1$
$$\therefore 1^{100} \leq 100^{100}\cdot 1! \quad\textbf{(true)}$$
\textbf{Induction Hypothesis}: Assume that for some arbitrary value, $n=k$, $k^{100} \leq 100^{100}\cdot k!$\
Induction Step: Showing for $n= k+1$ that:
\begin{align}
    (k+1)^{100} &\leq 100^{100}\cdot (k+1)!
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \Rightarrow (k)^{100} &\leq 100^{100}\cdot(k)! \nonumber    
\end{align}
Multiplying both sides by $(k+1)$ so that the RHS looks exactly like Eqn. 1:
\begin{align}
     \Rightarrow (k+1)(k)^{100} &\leq 100^{100}\cdot(k+1)(k)! \nonumber \\
     (k+1)(k)^{100} &\leq 100^{100}\cdot(k+1)! \nonumber
\end{align}
N.B: For the LHS
\begin{align}
    (k+1)(k)^{100} &< (k+1)(k+1)^{100} \nonumber \\
    \Rightarrow (k)^{100} &< (k+1)^{100} \nonumber
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
  \Rightarrow  (k+1)(k)^{100} &< (k+1)(k+1)^{100} \leq 100^{100}\cdot(k+1)! \nonumber \\
 \Rightarrow (k+1)(k+1)^{100} &\leq 100^{100}\cdot(k+1)! \nonumber \\
  \Rightarrow (k+1)^{100} &\leq 100^{100}\cdot(k+1)! \nonumber 
\end{align}
This proves:
$$k^{100} \leq 100^{100}\cdot k! \quad \text{for all $n\geq 1$}$$
That means $n^{100} \leq 100^{100}\cdot n!$ for all values of $n\geq 1$.\\
Therefore,
$$n^{100} \in O(n!)$$